# Problem executing a class when using PHP CLI

Tags: php, class, command-line, command-line-interface

I created a file test.class.php containing the following code in a LAMP environment:

```
<?php

class MyClass 
{
    public var $variable;
};

$obj = new MyClass();

?>
```

When I run:

```
php myclass.php
```

from the command line, I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /path/html/_dev/classes/test.class.php on line 5

If I access the same file via the browser, I get no errors. Any suggestions on what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The PHP CLI version that the PHP command defaults to in my environment is PHP 4.4.8.

My host also has a PHP5 command set up to use PHP 5.2.14.  When I executed the command

```
PHP5 myclass.php
```

Everything worked correctly.  However, the code I posted originally produced another error. The

```
public var $variable
```

line, which was a solution to another Stack Overflow post didn't work. I replaced it with

```
public $variable
```

and was able to test succesfully with that change.

This link helped out a lot
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/4319-error-on-yiibase-php-on-line-55/

Answer (score 4):

You do not need the `var` keywords ; you should use :

```
public $variable;
```

That's the correct PHP 5 syntax.

`var` is a reliquate of PHP 4, with which you'd have used :

```
var $variable;
```

But there was no `public` keyword in PHP 4 -- and `public` *(PHP 5)* and `var` *(PHP 4)* can't be used together.

For more informations about `public`, `var`, and other keywords of the same kind, see this page of the PHP manual : [**Visibility**][1]

As to why your code doesn't display any error when run by your webserver... Maybe a difference of configuration, that causes errors not to be displayed, in one case ?

Note : CLI and PHP/Apache can use different configuration files -- and often do.

---

As a sidenote *(it causes no problem)*, you don't need the semi-colon at the end of the class' definition : your code should look like this :

```
class MyClass 
{
    public $variable;
}

$obj = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're running `php5`'s cli:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Aug 22 2010 19:41:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

You can check which version of php you're using or where it's located with this command: `which php`.

And as the other guys said, get rid of this `var`. But it doesn't seem to be the problem. The error is reporting that `private` is an unknown token.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. Additionally, I found that my host has the PHP5 command available, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `var` keyword, it's not necessary.

```
<?php

class MyClass 
{
    public $variable;
};

$obj = new MyClass();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`public var $variable;` is too much. Just use one of those keywords.